# How to configure permalinks (.htaccess) for Wordpress in subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The problem: I can't create friendly permalinks using Wordpress.

We are running Apache. I am attempting to modify .htaccess, but with no success.

Here is the original content of my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I found a guy with a similar problem, but for him the `/blog` was in a nested subdirectory. See [this post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/404-when-permalinks-turned-on-with-blog-in-subdirectory)

Here is his solution:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/user/
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

    <Directory "/home/user">
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride none
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/home/user/blog">
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /blog/
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule . index.php [L]

      Options FollowSymLinks
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I think my answer is in his solution, but I can't figure out how to modify this snippet for my particular case. My Wordpress is in the `domain.com/blog` directory.

Comment: You need to use/set `AllowOverride All` before your using Mod-Rewrite (on `.htaccess`)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must say to the Host, that other files (like `.htaccess`) is allowed to override rules.

**Virtual Host**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/user/
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

    <Directory "/home/user">
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride none
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/home/user/blog">
      Options FollowSymLinks
      ## ADD THESE!
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Otherwise you can **remove** your complete blog-directives (`<Directory "/home/user/blog">`) and set the `AllowOverride none` to `AllowOverride All`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/user/
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

    <Directory "/home/user">
      Options FollowSymLinks
      # Change this!
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Than you can work with your rewriting on your `.htaccess` (`/home/user/blog/.htaccess`):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /blog/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here, a little example from my site:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin support@adi-code.de
    ServerName adi-code.de
    ServerAlias adi-code.de www.adi-code.de *.adi-code.de
    DocumentRoot /opt/adi

    <Directory /opt/adi/>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/adicode_error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/adicode_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hi there. Part of my problem is knowing what to put for DocumentRoot and <Directory "?"> for my case, which is domain.com/blog ... Do you know how I would modify the virtual host file for this?

Comment: Why? You dont need to change the Virtual-Host. Your main site is available on `/home/user/` (www.example.com) and the blog on a sub-directory `/home/user/blog` (www.example.com/blog). **Edit** remove the `"`.

Comment: Thanks. Will give you tick when I can.